# Python で 32個の１次元配列全体を ビットシフトさせたい。

Tags: python

お世話になります。

【　使用言語　】

Python3

【　したいこと　】

今、Byte（8bit）長の配列（リスト）変数 a[32] の
　　32Byte全体分 を 256bit列 と考えた場合、
　　このビット列全体を Right Shift させたいのですが、
　　どうようにすればできるのでしょうか？

Python または numpy または scipy で
　　一発変換できる関数が存在するのでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/73170

Answer (score 1):

以下は 5 ビット右シフトする例です。バイト列を 256 ビット長の整数値に変換してシフトした後、8 ビット単位で整数値に戻しています。

```
>>> import re

>>> lst = list(iter(b'@12 Hello World, Good bye World.'))
>>> lst
[64, 49, 50, ..., 108, 100, 46]
>>> len(lst)
32

>>> list(map(lambda x: int(x, 2),
     re.findall('.{8}',
       format(sum([int(x)*(2**(8*(len(lst)-i-1))) for i, x in enumerate(lst)])>>5, '0256b')
     )))
[2, 1, 137, ..., 147, 99, 33]
```

これでは分かりにくいかと思いますので、例えば 32 ビット(4 バイト)右シフトしてみます。

```
>>> shifted = list(map(lambda x: int(x, 2),
     re.findall('.{8}',
       format(sum([int(x)*(2**(8*(len(lst)-i-1))) for i, x in enumerate(lst)])>>32, '0256b')
     )))

>>> str(''.join(map(chr, shifted)))
'\x00\x00\x00\x00@12 Hello World, Good bye Wo'
```

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。左シフトできました。お世話になりました。

Answer (score 0):

int8 が32個集まり256bitのintとなっている、という視点で実装してみました。
例では32bit分だけですが、任意の長さまで拡張可能です

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

DIGITS = 8

def print_bits(bits):
    for bit in bits:
        print np.binary_repr(bit).zfill(DIGITS)

# 右シフトして消滅するビットを得る(左詰め)
def get_underflow_bits(bits, n):
    return np.bitwise_and(2 ** DIGITS - 1, np.left_shift(bits, DIGITS - n))

# 右シフトした結果、隣の配列に移動したbitだけを返す
def get_underflows(bits, n):
    return np.insert(get_underflow_bits(bits, n), 0, 0)[:-1]

# 単純に右シフトした結果と、桁移動したもののORを取る
def right_shift(bits, n):
    return np.bitwise_or(np.right_shift(bits, n), get_underflows(bits, n))

sample = [255, 0, 255, 0]
print_bits(right_shift(sample, 3))
```

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。Left bit Shift できました。お世話になりました。

Answer (score 0):

一度大きな整数を作ってから右にシフトして配列に戻す実装です。ご参考になれば。

```
from functools import reduce


def shift(a, bits):
    D = 8
    n = len(a)
    value = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (e << (D * (n - 1 - i)) for i, e in enumerate(a)))
    value >>= bits
    s = '{:0{}b}'.format(value, len(a) * D)
    return [int(s[i * D:(i + 1) * D], 2) for i in range(n)]


a = [0b11111111, 0b01010101, 0b00001111]
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 0)))  # 11111111 01010101 00001111
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 1)))  # 01111111 10101010 10000111
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 2)))  # 00111111 11010101 01000011
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 3)))  # 00011111 11101010 10100001
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 4)))  # 00001111 11110101 01010000
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 5)))  # 00000111 11111010 10101000
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 6)))  # 00000011 11111101 01010100
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 7)))  # 00000001 11111110 10101010
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 8)))  # 00000000 11111111 01010101
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 9)))  # 00000000 01111111 10101010
print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in shift(a, 10)))  # 00000000 00111111 11010101
```

Comment: ご親切ありがとうございます。実は左シフトをしたかったのですが、Python初心者のため、記述頂きましたソースを参考に色々試してみましたが上手くいきませんでした。左シフトの場合は value <<= bits の行以外は、どのように変更すれば実現できますでしょうか？お手数をお掛けいたしますが、ご返信頂けますと嬉しく思います。どうぞ宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。左ビットシフトできました。お世話になりました。

Comment: 自己解決されたようですが、関数内の3行を

value <<= bits

s = '{:0{}b}'.format(value, len(a) * D + bits)

return [int(s[bits + i * D:bits + (i + 1) * D], 2) for i in range(n)]

などとするのがわかりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: この度は、お手数をお掛け致しました。ご指導頂きました左ビットシフト方法も参考にさせて頂きます。どうもお世話になりました。御免ください。